# SQL change format of Datepart Month

Tags: sql, format, datepart

How do you change the DATEPART format of the month to include the 0 in front of the month?

For instance 5 should be 05.

What I have tried, but none of it works, (only gives me 5)

Createdate = 2008-07-25 13:43:48.000

```
CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(MONTH,(CreatedDate)))
CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(MM,(CreatedDate)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from [SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

You can try

```
DECLARE @Createdate DATETIME = '2008-07-25 13:43:48.000'
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @Createdate, 3), 4, 2)
```

And here is an example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5643)

Comment: Ah brilliant, Exactly that. Oh Okay i see how you did that. Awesome, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I often use RIGHT as a cheap way to CONVERT.

```
select RIGHT(100+MONTH(CreatedDate),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

Createdate = `2008-07-25 13:43:48.000`

```
Replace(str(datepart(mm, CreatedDate), 2),' ','0')
```

Output: `07`

Comment: uhm, are you sure? because i hover over MM and it says month in SQL server manager (and there is no mm, only MM)